# difference with try/catch+await and await+then/catch in JS

Tags: javascript, async-await

Are there any differences in performance or error handling between these two codes?

#1

```
# promises is array of async function
myResult = [];
try {
    result = await Promise.all(promises);
    result.forEach(function (arg) {
        myResult.push(arg);
    });
} catch(err) {
    console.log("Error");
}
```

#2

```
# promises is array of async function
myResult = [];
await Promise.all(promises)
    .then(result => {
        result.forEach(function(arg) {
            myResult.push(arg);
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("Error");
    });
```

Comment: remove `await` in #2 code snippet, you should avoid using `await` with `.then` -- and now there is no difference between #1 & #2.

Comment: "*promises is array of async function*" is it really? The name (and its usage in your code) suggest its an array of promises, not of functions that return a promise when called

Answer (score 0):

The `catch` block in the second code is the part of the promise chain and has it's own benefit. It can also return another `Promise`. Since it returns another promise it can be chained too. Also `await` is unnecessary in the second case